# How should I switch based on the URL

Tags: go, go-gin

This is my URL in Postman: `http://localhost:8000/filter?Name=Srinu`

I am passing a query string to fetch records on the database based on a query.

In my database having Name, Gender, and Age, how should I write the switch statement based on the below code snippet, that I have to get data based on my query?

```
switch ? {
    case "Name":
        fiName := bson.D{{"Name", name}}
        err = uc.session.DB(DB_NAME).C(DB_COLLECTION).Find(fiName).All(&json1)

        if err == nil {
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.JSON(201, &json1)
        } else {
            c.JSON(500, gin.H{"result": "An error occured"})
        }
    case "Gender":
        fiGender := bson.D{{"Gender", gender}}
        err = uc.session.DB(DB_NAME).C(DB_COLLECTION).Find(fiGender).All(&json1)

        if err == nil {
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.JSON(201, &json1)
        } else {
            c.JSON(500, gin.H{"result": "An error occured"})
        }
    case "Age":
        fiAge := bson.D{{"Age", age}}
        err = uc.session.DB(DB_NAME).C(DB_COLLECTION).Find(fiAge).All(&json1)

        if err == nil {
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            c.JSON(201, &json1)
        } else {
            c.JSON(500, gin.H{"result": "An error occured"})
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
r := ctx.Request

r.ParseForm()
switch {
case len(r.Form["Name"]) > 0:
    name := r.Form["Name"][0]
    fiName := bson.D{{"Name", name}}
    err = uc.session.DB(DB_NAME).C(DB_COLLECTION).Find(fiName).All(&json1)
    ...
}
```

The call `r.ParseForm()` sets `r.Form` using data parsed from the request.

The field `r.Form` is a map of string slices. If a parameter is present in the query, then the length of the string slice for the parameter is greater than zero.

The statement `name := r.Form["Name"][0]` gets the first parameter value for `Name`. If request is `http://localhost:8000/filter?Name=Srinu&Name=Reflect`, then the second value `Reflect` is silently ignored.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [URL](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) to see the results you can [check](https://play.golang.org/p/oo_cnn2dAmf)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8000/filter?Name=Srinu")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    query :=u.RawQuery
    parsed, err := url.ParseQuery(query)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    switch true {
            case parsed.Get("Name") != "" :
            fmt.Println(parsed["Name"]) 
            case parsed.Get("Age") != "":
            fmt.Println(parsed["Age"])  
        default:
            return
    }

}
```